# MyFaces vs. Sun's Reference Implementation - latter not free?

Tags: java, jsf, facelets, sun, myfaces

Just a stupid beginner's question, which will be quickly solved, but I am curious.

http://www.irian.at/myfacesexamples/home.jsf says:

"MyFaces - The **free** JavaServer™ Faces Implementation"

Errr ... is Sun's implementation not free, then?

Thanks & Cheers
Er

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it could refer to MyFaces being free & open-source software, unlike (?) Sun's JSF implementation, even though the latter is "free as in beer". But note that [official MyFaces website](http://myfaces.apache.org/) doesn't use such a designation.

Further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_Libre

**Edit**: As pakore points out in comments, also [Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/) ([codename](http://blogs.oracle.com/rlubke/entry/project_mojarra_the_jsf_ri) for the JSF reference implementation) *is* "free as in liberty" (using the [CDDL license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Development_and_Distribution_License)). So, it remains somewhat unclear where the slogan "the free JavaServer Faces Implementation" at that [MyFaces examples site](http://www.irian.at/myfacesexamples/home.jsf) actually stems from. Maybe it doesn't matter too much. :-)

Comment: Em, Mojarra is open source as well. You can download the source code from their website. The license of the software is CDDL, which is free as in "freedom". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Development_and_Distribution_License

Comment: @pakore, ah, ok. I didn't know - that's why I put the (?) in there :-). Perhaps it wasn't free in the past, or then the person who created http://www.irian.at/myfacesexamples/home.jsf simply didn't know what he's talking about...

Comment: don't worry, I wrote that because I saw your "?" :). It would be nice that you edit your response, so other readers won't think Mojarra's not free :).